# Move a particular value object in array to end

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, sorting, underscore.js

I'm trying to find a way to move an object to the end of the array

I have this array of objects:

```js
[
  {"id":"4","name":"Boaz"},
  {"id":"2","name":"Shareen"},
  {"id":"3","name":"Simon"},
  {"id":"1","name":"Miriam"}
]
```

I want to move the whole set *{"id":"3","name":"Simon"}* to the end of it all. I have solution for this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24562280/move-object-in-array-to-end?noredirect=1&lq=1). But my problem is every time that particular object is not coming in second position is there a way to check the object of `id=3` and shift that to end using `underscoreJS`

Comment: Have you tried anything? I'm not sure what you've tried that is causing the problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Move object in array to end](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24562280/move-object-in-array-to-end)

Answer (score 8):

You can just sort array.

#### Explanation

[Array.sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) expects 3 possible values as return value.

- 1: means `a` is greater than `b` and `a` will be move to a higher index than `b`
- 0: means `a` is equal to `b` and no change will be made.
- -1: means `a` is less than `b` and `a` will be move to a lower index than `b`.

For more information please refer: [How does Javascript's sort() work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1494713/how-does-javascripts-sort-work)

```js
var data = [
  {"id":"4","name":"Boaz"},
  {"id":"2","name":"Shareen"},
  {"id":"3","name":"Simon"},
  {"id":"1","name":"Miriam"}
]

data.sort(function(a,b){
  return a.id == 3 ? 1 : 0
})

console.log(data)
```

---

An alternate method could to filter out objects with necessary id, remove them from current position and the push them back, but this is too much work in my understanding. Sort is ideal way to move object up or down the order.

Comment: can you explain what `return a.id == 3 ? 1 : 0`? didn't downvote

Comment: I don't think this answers his question, he is looking for something that moves the element with id: 3 to the end. yours would not work for something like [{id:3},{id:4}]. edit: in fact yours does not move the element with id: 3 to the end of the array.

Comment: @Rajesh my mistake, you are correct, I misread your sort condition. Apparently I can't change to an upvote unless you edit your answer... Maybe you could add a period to your last sentance ;) edit: upvoted

Comment: I just saw your answer and deleted my answer :p

Comment: Basically in sort function for every element in the array as "a" if you return 1 "a" will move up and if you return -1 it will move down and 0 will not affect the array "b" is the next element so you can compare with

Comment: See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Comment: from the description "If compareFunction(a, b) returns 0, leave a and b unchanged with respect to each other, but sorted with respect to all different elements. Note: the ECMAscript standard does not guarantee this behaviour, and thus not all browsers (e.g. Mozilla versions dating back to at least 2003) respect this."

Comment: No sort is working like reduce function if "a" replaced with "b" then it becomes the next "a" again in the 2nd call and if not "b" becomes the next "a" there is huge difference

Comment: you don't respect `b.id === '3'`, your sort is not symetrically.

Comment: @NinaScholz if `b` is `3` no change should happen. So adding `a.id==3 ? 1 : b.id==3?0:0` looked an overkill. Though I accept your point.

Comment: your sort fails on `var data = [
  {"id":"4","name":"Boaz"},
  {"id":"3","name":"Simon"},
  {"id":"2","name":"Shareen"},
  {"id":"1","name":"Miriam"}
]`

Comment: @NinaScholz `id:3` is still last. [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/p3gLdvv5/). Sorry if I'm not getting your point. Please feel free to edit/downvote if there is some major shortfall in code.

Comment: please try your sorting with my above posted array with edge.

Comment: I think @NinaScholz is right and we are both wrong every browser or environment may use deferent sorting algorithm for deferent case the JavaScrip let you defines the behaviour of the compare function, not how the actual sort is implemented.

Answer (score 3):

Do some simple array manipulation

```js
var obj = [{
    "id": "4",
    "name": "Boaz"
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "name": "Shareen"
  },
  {
    "id": "3",
    "name": "Simon"
  },
  {
    "id": "1",
    "name": "Miriam"
  }
];
obj.forEach(function(v, i) {
  if (v.id == 3) {//test to see if the id is 3
    obj.push(obj[i]);//push the object to the last position
    obj.splice(i, 1);//remove the object from the current position

  }

});
console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 3):

I suggest to use the delta of the comparison, not only if you have more than one true comparison, but you need a symetrically comparison, if `b` contains the item to sort at the end, then you get the order, you want.

```js
var array = [{ id: "4", name: "Boaz" }, { id: "2", name: "Shareen" }, { id: "3", name: "Simon" }, { id: "1", name: "Miriam" }];

array.sort(function (a, b) {
    return (a.id === '3') - (b.id === '3');
});

console.log(array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: what is the deferent ?!! why would you sort the last elements in the array ?!

Comment: @fareednamrouti, i don't get you, what is the question?

Comment: I mean why would we need to check if b.id === "3" if It is already in higher position ?!

Comment: how do you know that, that the only the left part is important? the sort mechanism of the language is vendor specific. if you rely only on one side, you could get the wrong result.

Comment: I checked the documentation and you are 100% right. The JavaScript standard only defines the behaviour of the compare function, not how the actual sort is implemented. That parts depends on the vendor/environment.

Answer (score 1):

While there isnt an "out-of-the-box" underscore function, we can extend the base library with our own function using the [`_.mixin()`](http://underscorejs.org/#mixin) function.

The extension works by using the underscore [`_.indexOf()`](http://underscorejs.org/#indexOf) function to return the index of an element that matches a predicate. We then use the native JS [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) function, to remove `1` item at the returned index (*Note that this will leave the array unaffected if `_.indexOf` returns `-1`*). As per the docs, `splice`, returns an array of all elements that were removed. We, lastly use the native JS [`concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) function, which merges two (or more) arrays together, to put the returned value from the `concat` on to the end of the supplied array (`arr`).

**UnderscoreJS extending**

```
(function(_) {
    "use strict";
    _.mixin({
        moveToEndWhere: moveToEndWhere
    });

    /**
     * @function moveToEndWhere
     * @desc Searches an array for the first item matching a predicate, and moves the matched element to the end of the array
     * @param {array} arr Array to be searched and altered
     * @param {function|object} predicate Function or object used to search for matching element
     * @returns {array} Updated array
     * @memberof _.mixin
     */
    function moveToEndWhere(arr, predicate){
        return arr.concat(
            arr.splice(
                _.indexOf(arr, predicate)
                , 1
            )
        );
    }
})(_);
```

**Usage**

```
var data = [
    {"id":"4","name":"Boaz"},
    {"id":"2","name":"Shareen"},
    {"id":"3","name":"Simon"},
    {"id":"1","name":"Miriam"}
];

data = _.moveToEndWhere(data, {"id":3});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function findIdIndex(id, array) {
  return array.findIndex(elem=>elem.id===id);
}
```

This will give you the position of the set with the given id, the answer to your previous question covers the rest of what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

first write a method like this,send the value as '3' and get the index and `attr` as `id`

```
function getElementIndex(array, attr, value) {
    for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i += 1) {
        if(array[i][attr] === value) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

By this method you can use any property to get the data with.

Then write

```
var index=getElementIndex(array,'id','3');//here array is your data array you have 
var itemToReplace = array.splice(index, 1); 

array = array.concat(itemToReplace);
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this with the getting index of the respective object and then check the position:

```js
var array  = [{ "id": "4", "name": "Boaz" }, { "id": "2", "name": "Shareen" }, { "id": "3", "name": "Simon" }, { "id": "1", "name": "Miriam" }];

var index =  array.findIndex(x => x.id == 3);

if(index === 2) {
 var person =  array.splice(index, 1);
 array  = array.concat(person);
}

console.log(array)
```