# Get an item in an array to first position according to a condition

Tags: javascript

Hey I have the following array :

```
var ar = [{id: "F"}, {id: "G"}, {id: "Z"}, {id: "ZZ"}]
```

I would like to move the one with the id equals to `ZZ` to the first position in the array.
I know how to do it using several different functions, but I was wondering if there was an elegant solution to do it (lodash, ...)

Comment: Can you show non-elegant version with several functions?

Comment: _.find / delete / _.merge

Comment: You can refer following post.  Its reverse but should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42479079/move-a-particular-value-object-in-array-to-end/42479198#42479198

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `unshift()` to add to start of array and `splice()` and `findIndex()` to get object by id.

```js
var arr = [{id: "F"}, {id: "G"}, {id: "Z"}, {id: "ZZ"}]
arr.unshift(arr.splice(arr.findIndex(e => e.id == "ZZ"), 1)[0])

console.log(arr)
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var ar = [{
  id: "F"
}, {
  id: "G"
}, {
  id: "Z"
}, {
  id: "ZZ"
}];
ar.sort(function(a, b) {
  if (a.id === "ZZ") {
    return -1;
  }
  if (b.id === "ZZ") {
    return 1;
  }
  return 0;
});
console.log(ar);
```

How about sorting it?

Comment: I have answer a post in a similar fashion: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42479198/3783478

Comment: `Array#sort` is not guaranteed to be stable, so this could result in all the elements other than `ZZ` being in a completely new order from where they started.

Comment: Aye, just for matching the word "elegant" in the question. :) @JLRishe

Comment: @blackmiaool I don't consider a solution that might produce the wrong result to be "elegant".

Comment: @JLRishe  Those elegant es6 code can't even run in some old browswers.